# Can I "left join" days between 2 dates in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There is a table in SQL Server where data is entered day by day. In this table, data is not filled in some days.

Therefore, there are no records in the table.

Sample: dataTable

[image]

I need to generate a report like the one below from this table.

[image]

Create a table with all the days of the year. I know that I can output a report by "joining" the "dataTable" table.

But this solution seems a bit strange to me.

Is there another way?

the code i use for temp date table

```
CREATE TABLE tempDate (
  calendarDate date,
  PRIMARY KEY (calendarDate)
)

DECLARE
  @start DATE= '2021-01-01',
  @dateCount   INT= 730,
  @rowNumber   INT=1
  
WHILE (@rowNumber < @dateCount)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tempDate values (DATEADD(DAY, @rowNumber, @start))
  set @rowNumber=@rowNumber+1
END

GO
select * from tempDate
```

This is how I join using this table

```
SELECT
        *
FROM
        tempDate td WITH (NOLOCK)
        LEFT JOIN dataTable dt WITH (NOLOCK) ON dt.reportDate = td.calendarDate
WHERE
        td.calendarDate BETWEEN '2021-09-05' AND '2021-09-15'
```

Comment: Problems like this are solved easily with a [Calendar tale](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/), a table with dates for the next eg 20 years with any extra fields that may be useful to make reporting easier, eg Year, Month, Quarter etc. This makes querying a *lot* faster because the server can take advantage of the columns on the date fields

Comment: Why is creating a calendar table to support business requirements (like a list of dates regardless of data) "strange"? It's actually quite common and useful. See [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) and [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6844/sql-server-calendar-table-example/) for examples. You absolutely don't _need_ a calendar table, you can generate the list dynamically, but a table you reference often will be in memory so I'm really not sure why people are so opposed to it...

Comment: Maybe a CTE like this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166024/how-to-create-a-row-for-every-day-in-a-date-range-using-a-stored-procedure. But like the idea of a table as mentioned above

Comment: If you try to group over `YEAR(dateField)` the server won't be able to use the indexes that cover `dateField` and will have to scan the entire table. If you group by `Calendar.Year` the server will be able to use the indexes o `Calendar.Date`, `dateField` and if it exists, `Calendar.Year` to select and group only the rows that match this year using index seeks

Comment: I updated [this answer on DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/75486/1186) that may also be useful.

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use common expression tables for dates. The code you need:

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #t
END

CREATE TABLE #t
    (
    id int,
    dt date,
    dsc varchar(100),
    )

INSERT INTO #t 
VALUES
    (1, '2021.09.08', 'a'),
    (1, '2021.09.09', 'b'),
    (1, '2021.09.12', 'c')

DECLARE @minDate AS DATE
SET @minDate = (SELECT MIN(dt) FROM #t)
DECLARE @maxDate AS DATE
SET @maxDate = (SELECT MAX(dt) FROM #t)

;WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT @minDate AS [dt]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [dt])
    FROM cte
    WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, [dt])<=@maxDate
)

SELECT 
    ISNULL(CAST(t.id AS VARCHAR(10)), '') AS [id],
    cte.dt AS [dt],
    ISNULL(t.dsc, 'No record has been entered in the table.') AS [dsc]
FROM 
    cte
    LEFT JOIN #t t on t.dt=cte.dt
```

Comment: Be careful with a recursive date CTE - both performance at scale and you'll need `MAXRECURSION` if min/max > 100 days apart.

Answer (score 6):

> Create a table with all the days of the year. I know that I can output a report by "joining" the "dataTable" table.

This is the way.  You can generate that "table" on the fly if you really want to, but normally the best way is to simply have a calendar table.

Comment: I've currently created a table with all the days for 2021 and 2022. This is how I use it but the user will need me again after 2 years. I asked just to be sure. I will use this way.

Comment: @omerix Why not put 10 years of data in the table? Or 30 years? The table is not large and proper indexing will make sure that the commonly-used pages will be in memory.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest method is to use a numbers table, you can get a date list between 2 dates with that:

```
DECLARE @Date1 DATE, @Date2 DATE
SET @Date1 = '20200528'
SET @Date2 = '20200625'

SELECT DATEADD(DAY,number+1,@Date1) [Date]
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEADD(DAY,number+1,@Date1) < @Date2
```

If you go go in `LEFT JOIN` this select, whit your table, you have the result that you want.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DATEADD(DAY,number+1,@Date1) [Date]
      FROM master..spt_values WITH (NOLOCK) 
      WHERE type = 'P'
        AND DATEADD(DAY,number+1,@Date1) < @Date2 ) as a
LEFT JOIN yourTable dt WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.date = dt.reportDate  
WHERE td.[Date] BETWEEN '2021-09-05' AND '2021-09-15'
```